# HashMap - using custom data objects

Tags: get, hashmap, containskey

Suppose, I have a HashMap:

```
HashMap<MyKey, Integer> HM = new HashMap<MyKey, Integer>();
```

MyKey corresponds to a data object with two integer elements (and a constructor for passing two integers).

```
HM.put(new MyKey(1,1234), 1); // this seems to work...
```

but, I cannot seem to use it:

```
System.out.println(HM.containsKey(new MyKey(1,1234)));
```

I get false.

Can a HashMap have a custom data object for a Key? What am I missing?  Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override the `equals()` and `hashcode()` method in your MyKey class (or any other custom class for that matter that would go into a HashMap or Set). That way, when you say `containsKey()` (or the Set method`contains()`, or `equals()`), you would have explicitly specified what properties of MyKey to check for containment or equality.

You could have a simple `equals()` and `hashCode()` method like this in your MyKey class

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    boolean result = false;
    if (o instanceof MyKey) {
        MyKey mykey = (MyKey) o;
        result = (this.getX() == mykey.getX() && mykey.getY() == mykey.getY());
    }
    return result;
}

@Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + X;
        result = prime * result + Y;
        return result;
    }
```

(Assuming the fields in your MyKey class are X and Y)

Comment: If I try: System.out.println(HM.containsKey(MyKey(1,1234)));

Comment: I then get "cannot find symbol" (referring to MyKeys).  Linguistically, I find it quite odd that I can put the item in, but then I actually have to have the originally specified item, not a copy of it. In any case, thanks for the help.  I am iterating the HashList to find the actual item.

Comment: @n as
I have edited my answer. When overriding equals, hashCode should also be overriden. Also, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your System.out, you're generating a `new MyKey()`. You want to check if your hashmap contains a `MyKey(1,1234)`, not a `new MyKey(1,1234)`.

Comment: but if it compiles, it means `containsKey` do require a pointer, doesn't it?

Comment: Not necessarily - it depends on the specific implementation of hashmap that the OP is using. It could just as happily compile with the new statement (and never return true) as it could with a reference to an existing object.